# Change CSS with python and Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I wan't to change a css line from python/Flask/Jinja2 in my css file like this:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='./css/index.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='./img/icon.png') }}">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="marquee">
        <div class="v-align">
            <p style="font-size:20vh;"><b>{{ text }}</b></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.v-align {
   font-size: 120px;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.marquee {
   vertical-align: middle;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   color: "red";
}

.marquee p {
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 100%;
   animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee {
   0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
   100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

I want to replace the 30s by any value when rendering it with python.

Python:

```
return render_template("my_html_file.html", text="this is a test!", animation_time="30s")
```

It seems to be impossible to make it in thr CSS file like this: `animation: marquee {{ animation_time }} linear infinite;`
, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Is the css written in `my_html_file.html` or in a separate `.css` file?

Comment: It's hard to judge what the sought-after answer to this question is. I've provided an answer about the CSS animation-duration property, which the question seems to hint that the OP doesn't know about, but there could be a number of things the OP doesn't quite understand that make finding the solution difficult.

Comment: @yaswanth It is in a separate .css file, because I can't put it in the .html file

Comment: @my_name Why not? You can just take that line out and put it in the HTML file in a <style> tag with the proper selector.

Comment: @my_name, can you post your css and HTML files ?

Comment: @yaswanth I edited my post!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically what you have done will not work as you are passing `animation_time` to the `HTML template` and not the `CSS file`. One way would be to add css within the `HTML` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='./css/index.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='./img/icon.png') }}">
    <style>
        .marquee p {
            display: inline-block;
            padding-left: 100%;
            animation: marquee {{animation_time}}s linear infinite;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="marquee">
        <div class="v-align">
            <p style="font-size:20vh;"><b>{{ text }}</b></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
return render_template("my_html_file.html", text="this is a test!", animation_time="30")
```

In general, it's not recommended to generate css files on the fly as they are mostly static and is preferred to serve them from CDN. I'm not sure if you can inject variables into a css file and link it with `link` tag to the current `html` file.

If you really have the above use case, I would suggest to use inline styles within the html file.

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked around this by leaving the lines I needed to edit in the CSS out of the actual CSS file and putting them in a style tag of the document itself via the same script.

Here is the code for that;

```
    username = sys.argv[1]
inset = ['''<style> ''',username,'''{
  background-color: #5bb235 !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
'''
,username,''' :hover{
  background-color: #dddddd !Important;
  color: #462955 !important;
}
</style>
<div id="calendar"><div id="calendar_header"><h1></h1></div><div id="calendar_weekdays"></div><div id="calendar_content">
''']
```

What this means is that I have to pass the variable 'username' via an argument when running the script - I don't know if it's the best solution out there, but it worked for me in 3.6.

Comment: Is it in the .css file or where do you put it? I don't understand your answer

Comment: This solution takes the Styles that need changed out of the CSS document and in to a <style></style> within the HTML, PHP or whatever front-facing file you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `animation-duration` to accomplish this in an inline style on the page you are rendering. CSS that is encountered later in the document overrides earlier rules, so adding this after the link to your stylesheet should accomplish what you want.

[animation-duration on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration)

Comment: The problem is that I cannot dynamicaly edit the time within the .css file